# Does a Unix process automatically get supplemental-groups permissions?

Tags: linux, unix, permissions, file-permissions, gid

User `spock` belongs to groups `human` and `vulcan`.

File `holo` is owned by user `root` and by group `vulcan`. Its permissions are `rwxrwx---` (770).

Process `tractor` is started by user `spock`, and has uid `spock` and primary gid `human`.

Will `tractor` automatically have access to `holo`, or will it have to explicitly request the supplemental group permissions of `spock` via an `initgroups` call?

[The comment here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206289/how-do-linux-permissions-work-when-a-process-is-running-as-a-specific-group#comment348068_206304) says that it has to be designed to make an explicit request, but [the credentials manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html) does not mention anything like that and seems (to me) to imply that the supplemental-group checking is automatically done by the OS.

Answer (score 1):

Just so long as the permissions were in place before the `tractor` process was started it will have access to the file 'holo' because it's part of the 'vulcan' group.

If you start the `tractor` process then add the 'spock' user to the 'vulcan' group it may not work.